# Android: Unable to return number from startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I am trying to write an app that has two buttons - the first brings up a list of contacts and the second sends a message to the selected contact. I am able to select a contact using startActivityForResult and onActivityResult, but I cannot return the contact's number to my main code where it would be read by the second button's onClick method. When running the code below, I get the toast message with the phone number but when I try to send a message I get the "Please select a contact first" message. I don't know how to make the "phoneNumber" variable in onActivityResult to send it to "phoneNumber" in my main activity. Thanks!

```
package com.example.testa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidAlarmService extends Activity { 
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0; 
    private static final Uri CONTACTS_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI; 
    static String phoneNumber = ""; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    final Button contacts_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getContacts);         
    contacts_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, CONTACTS_CONTENT_URI); 

                intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                Log.e("AAS", "Found an error in contacts button");
            } 
        } 
    });
    final Button send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button); 
    send_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            final String yourtext = "my message";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
            if (phoneNumber == ""){
                Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Please select a contact first" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //This is the message I get
                return;
            }
            myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            myIntent.putExtra("yourtext", yourtext);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        }});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                        null, null, null);
                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    int type = c.getInt(1);
                    showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //this part is working
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String number = c.getString(0);
```

to

```
phoneNumber = c.getString(0);
```

This will store the phone number in the member variable rather than in a local variable. Now you can use this `phoneNumber` member variable in the click listener for your second button.

Note that `phoneNumber == ""` is an error. You should use `equals()` to compare `String` instances for equality.